# Boku wa ikanaide

Tags: translation

Can "boku wa ikanaide" be translated as “please don't leave me”? Is it grammatically correct and informal?

Comment: No.  Can you explain what leads you to believe it means that?  Did you see/hear that in some context that might have made you think that?

Comment: i saw my friend saying it on tiktok and was wondering if its correct since it seems off. im curious, what would be the correct way of saying it??

Answer (score 1):

Is this friend of yours a native speaker?

行く doesn't have the "leave behind" meaning, so that wouldn't be good even with whatever particle you use.

You can take the で away but then it would have a totally different meaning.

I would say something like

> 私を置いていかないで。 Don't leave me behind.

Comment: As for the particle, I guess it could either be a typo or not, that is, it could be は. Although using it in the construct 僕はおいて行かないで sounds a bit weird to me, something like スーツはおいて行かないで is perfectly fine, putting an emphasis on the object being left behind by making it the topic.